# Java SQLite JDBC DriverManager.getConnection null on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, raspberry-pi2

I am using SQLite JDBC to access SQL databases on my Raspberry Pi vB+ ARMv7.
The code throws a `NullPointerException` because `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:LECT_USERS.db");` returns `null`.

The code works fine on Windows 10.

I have tried using `Class.forName(..)` but it made no difference for me.

Please help me fix this as I've gone through a lot of trouble to get the library working on ARM.

**Edit**

I added a `null` check before accessing the `connection` object. Now the code throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:161)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:220)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

According to the JDBC GitHub issues about this, this problem can be fixed by **compiling the latest snapshot yourself**, <s>and then copying the native lib from /ARM to /Linux/armhf</s>.

**Edit**

link to compiled JDBC version 3.13.0-SNAPSHOT: https://mega.nz/#!IMsRnZ7I!YOXoRjswPigMHchFi-k-b1czyIGDt5nj5IgnMW7yLT0

Comment: well you have to use `Class.forName(..)` in order to load the right class at Runtime. You probably need to post some more code if you want help

Comment: This is all the code I have. I call getConnection and it returns null. Edit: why is Class.forName necessary? It works fine without on Windows

Comment: Take a look at this issue https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/97